# Filter on html tag

Tags: html, filter

With html bookmark saved from chrome or others, frequently exported as html file that comes with `<a href` tag that I'd like to filter and arrange:

```
<a href="https://<a-web-site>">Title of the website</a>
```

How to use basic linux's util like sed/grep/awk to filter and arrange items like:

```
Title of the website https://<a-web-site>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
$ echo '<a href="https://<a-web-site>">Title of the website</a>' | sed -e 's|.*href="\(.*\)".*>\(.*\)</a>|\2 \1|g'
Title of the website https://<a-web-site>
```